# Change type of jQuery Jeditable after initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jeditable

I have a [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) element, which starts out as a text-editable element. However, based on user choice, I would like to change this to a `select` type. Is this possible?

If the editable element is a table cell (`td`), and the answer is to replace that cell with  a new element and new Jeditable, how does one do that in jQuery? The `replaceWith` function gives the error `Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null` when I try to replace the cell with a new cell.

Answer (score 0):

how about making the two types, then just show/hide for which is needed.

for example, make the `text-editable` and `select type` but `select type` is hidden. when user choose `select type`, you hide `text-editable` and show `select type`.

Comment: That's a good idea, but unfortunately that would require me creating a whole range of different `select` type editables (one of every set of options) in every cell in my grid, which amounts to a few thousand in this case.

Comment: The answer does very possibly solve the problem so I upvoted it to 0 becuse I think it didn't devere a -1.